# Handsontable & different datepicker

Tags: jquery, handsontable, daterangepicker

I don't really like handsontable's datepicker and want to use my own (daterangepicker). Is there an easy way to specify a different datepicker, or just add a class to a cell so I can use daterangepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no **easy** way.

It is possible, but you would have to write your own [custom cell editor](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.4.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html) and override the Pikaday datepicker.

Similar issue on GitHub: [Is it possible to change the default datepicker?](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1055)